# One function for two models in MVC in PHP

Tags: php, model-view-controller, methods

I have function friendlyUrl() among model methods in shop for creating friendly urls for items.

And I need use this function friendlyUrl() for articles in blog in the same website. I think duplicate it to blog model methods in not good idea.

Where to place this function or how to call it? Do I have simply to require shop model methods in blog and call this function?
What is best solution for this example?

Thank you very much.

Comment: How exactly is this related to MVC?

Comment: Put that friendlyUrl() in a common file and you can include that file where ever required. you can call that function directly.

Comment: Your core controller can offer shared functionality (e.g. `friendlyUrl()` ), which all of your 'sub' controllers can utilize as they extend the core controller.

Comment: You could also create a trait, and attach it to both of the models.

Comment: "Pretty URLs" are handled by routing code and (if you need to generate them) helper functions in the templates. They have NOTHING to do with MVC architectural pattern, since "web" as such is just an external detail.

Comment: Im sorry. There was mistake in my description. I exchange word method and model.

Comment: I need call friendlyUrl() method in 2 controllers. I use this method for transform title to frindly url and store to db. And it looks, the best place for this method is in helpers directory. Thanks to all for help and tips.

Comment: No, it is not. Controllers should not even be aware, that a storage (of any kind) exists and the construction of a specialized string (which that "pretty URL" would be) for purposes of storing it in DB should be done either in domain entities OR (better option) using a specialized [value object](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/ValueObject.html). Of course, you are seemingly ignoring the option, that you should not actually store the pretty URL string in database and instead build it at runtime in a template.

Answer (score 0):

Do these methods accomplish this task in a similar way?

If so, I would suggest moving it to Traits. In MVC, traits are especially welcome in cases when the Model must have the functionality that the Service has and the business concept for it is

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO! It would improve your answer if you could add an example, reference, or link to documentation to illustrate the reasoning behind your answer. Thank you for contributing!